# Setting up python on windows 10 pro

Tags: python, windows, pip, path, windows-10

Have set up **Python 3.5** and **Python 2.7.11** yet both have not been recognized by the command prompt. Also have download **pip.py**, and the command prompt has not recognized it. Have set the PATH to 
`C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python34\Scripts\;`

And have also added the Python 3.5 to PATH through the installation prompts. The computer is a Dell and is a Windows 10 pro computer.

`'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.`

`'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.`

Comment: Maybe you should try Anaconda or Python(x,y)

Comment: Or read installation options.  See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a variable called **PYTHONPATH**, follow the following steps

navigate to `My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables >`

Then under system variables create a new Variable called `PythonPath`.

In this variable include `C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\other-foolder-on-the-path`

(no extra spaces)

[image]

if someone is there that above is not working, then kindly append to your PATH with the `C:\Python27` then it should surely work

for complete details here is a link [document](http://python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using/windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the path after your modifications?  You may need to close and reopen console windows, or even reboot to update your environment variables.

Instead, try `py`, which is the Python Launcher.  It should be installed in C:\Windows which is already in the path.  It was an option during install (seee options at bottom of dialog below).  Adding Python to the path is also an option, but installing two versions makes only the first one in the path work.

[image]

It allows you to pick the version of Python to run:

```
py         # Run default python version...PY_PYTHON env. var can override this.
py -3      # Run the latest Python3 found on the system.
py -2      # Run the latest Python2 found on the system.
py -2.7    # Specifically run Python 2.7.
py -2.7-32 # Specifically run 32-bit Python 2.7 on a 64-bit system.
```

You can also add a `#!python3` comment to the top of a script and double-clicking the file in Explorer will use that version of Python.

See: [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)